# input en tabla html que acepte solo números

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tengo una tabla a la que le añado columnas con celdas `input`, dentro de ella estoy tratando de hacer que me acepte solo números de la siguiente manera :

```
    var table = document.getElementById("tabProd");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var columna3=document.createElement("td");
    var celda3 = document.createElement("input");
    celda3.addEventListener('blur',cambiaCantidad,true);
    celda3.addEventListener('keypress',return soloNumeros(event));
    columna3.appendChild(celda3);
    row.appendChild(columna3);
    table.appendChild(row);
```

La función es la siguiente:

```
    function soloNumeros(e){
    var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key===8)); 
    }
```

tambien probe con esta función que encontre pero sigue sin funcionar

```
function soloNumeros(e){
tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

//Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
if (tecla===8){
    return true;
}
 // Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros
patron =/[0-9]/;
tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

Sin embargo no funciona ninguno, como debería añadirlo dentro del `AddEventListener`

Comment: Muestra la parte del código donde estás añadiendo celda3 a su elemento padre

Comment: listo @CamiloVasquez ya esta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el método `addEventListener` deberías indicar únicamente la función que hará de controlador del evento.

Esta función ya se llamará recibiendo el objeto de definición del evento como argumento.

Para cancelar el evento la forma más consistente es invocar el método `preventDefault` del objeto `Event`, que se encargará de evitar que el navegador responda con el comportamiento por defecto al evento (en este caso evitará que añada el carácter correspondiente a la tecla pulsada):

```js
var table = document.getElementById("tabProd");
var row = document.createElement("tr");
var columna3=document.createElement("td");
var celda3 = document.createElement("input");
//celda3.addEventListener('blur',cambiaCantidad,true);
celda3.addEventListener('keydown', soloNumeros);
columna3.appendChild(celda3);
row.appendChild(columna3);
table.appendChild(row);


function soloNumeros(e){
  var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  
  if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && (key!==8))
    e.preventDefault();  
}
```

```html
<table id="tabProd"></table>
```

Una alternativa utilizando jQuery y `keypress`.

La opción de usar `keypress` evita filtrar las teclas no editables (flechas, suprimir, retroceso) con lo que únicamente habría que comprobar las editables.

Además al utilizar jQuery unificamos el comportamiento de los navegadores por lo que no hay que preocuparse por posibles incompatibilidades entre ellos.

También he cambiado la validación, definiendo una función que comprueba si es un dígito, y otra que comprueba si es un punto y no existe ya uno (para que no se puedan introducir dos separadores de decimales).

```js
$(function(){
  var $table = $("#tabProd");
  var $row = $("<tr>");
  var $columna3 = $("<td>");
  var $celda3 = $("<input>");
  $celda3.keypress(soloNumeros);
  $columna3.append($celda3);
  $row.append($columna3);
  $table.append($row);
});

function soloNumeros(e){
  var key = e.which;
  // Dígito código entre 48 y 57
  var isDigit = (d) => d >=48 && d<=57;
  // Punto código 46, sólo si no hay uno anterior
  var isValidSeparator = (d, current) => d===46 && current.indexOf('.') <0;
  if (!isDigit(key) && !isValidSeparator(key, $(this).val()))
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabProd"></table>
```

Comment: gracias Asier, como haria para que de igual manera me acepte solo una coma o un punto ?

Comment: Podrías ir añadiendo códigos de tecla válidos. En este caso el de la coma sería el código 188, el del punto el 190 y el del separador decimal del teclado numérico el 110.

Comment: y puedo añadirle jquery a este código porque el control de numeros lo hacia de la siguiente manera: $('#cant').numeric(); pero no se si se pueda

Comment: He modificado la respuesta para añadir un ejemplo utilizando jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma fácil de lograr que quieres es aprovechar los atributos que brinda HTML indicándole al tu `<input>` que sea de tipo numérico:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("tabProd");
var row = document.createElement("tr");
var columna3 = document.createElement("td");
var celda3 = document.createElement("input");

//celda3.addEventListener('blur',cambiaCantidad,true);
celda3.setAttribute('type', 'number');
columna3.appendChild(celda3);
row.appendChild(columna3);
table.appendChild(row);
```

```html
<table id="tabProd"></table>
```

Comment: no lo hice de esa forma porque aunque indique que es de tipo numérico me acepta la letra e, y ademas acepta . y ,